# scrollTo is not a function

Tags: jquery, function, scrollto

Ok, I can't see it anymore. I'm using [the scrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) and have a scrollTo function  in my website. It worked and now suddenly it doesn't...

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('header').delay(300).fadeIn(750);
    $('#intro_text').delay(800).fadeIn(750);
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                m4v: "mi4.m4v",
                ogv: "mi4.ogv",
                webmv: "mi4.webm",
                poster: "mi4.png"
            });
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "webmv, ogv, m4v",
        size: {
            width: "570px",
            height: "340px",
            cssClass: "jp-video-360p"
        }
    });
});

$(function(toDemos) {
 $('h1').click(function() {
        $.scrollTo('#intro', 800);
    });
});

$(function(toDemos) {
 $('#contact').click(function() {
        $.scrollTo('footer', 800);
    });
});

$(function(toDemos) {
 $('#demos').click(function() {
        $.scrollTo('#content', 800);
    });
});

$(function(toDemos) {
 $('#toTop').click(function() {
        $.scrollTo('#intro', 800);
    });
});

$(function() {
    $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
        $("#videoarea").attr({
            "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
            "poster": "",
            "autoplay": "autoplay"
        })
    })
    $("#videoarea").attr({
        "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
        "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
    })
})
```

I'm just a beginner at this, but I don't think I did much wrong.
Is there anything wrong here? I can't see it.

Hopefully one of you can! Much thanks in advance.

Comment: Using flesler's scrollTo plugin?

Comment: yes I did use that one. And it worked. but then I added the  "$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({" function and a while later it didn't work anymore. im lost

Comment: 1.  remove what you added just to see if functionality returns.  2.  If it returns to functional state, determine the conflict between them.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using [flesler's scrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html), you may need to modify the duration option:

```
$.scrollTo('footer', { duration:800 });
```

Download the plugin source [here](http://flesler-plugins.googlecode.com/files/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1-min.js) if you haven't already. I would verify that it is correctly linked to your code. Also try a debugging tool like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to help with the troubleshooting.

**NOTE:**

To point out [Mark's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125981/mark-schultheiss) answer in the comments below for anyone who stumbles on this, jQuery must be linked first in order in the file before any plugins are loaded. E.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am using Firebug, it says this:

"TypeError: $.scrollTo is not a function
$.scrollTo('#content', 800);"

Comment: You mean how all the functions all called toDemos?

Comment: have you included jQuery into your project?

Comment: yes: "<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>"

Comment: And also: "<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1-min.js"></script>"

Comment: @Luc - and hopefully loaded in that order you listed them.

Comment: uh yes first the jquery and then the scrollTo

Comment: And then some other stuff for jPlayer

Comment: Download flesler's `scrollTo` plugin from [HERE](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/releases)

Answer (score 1):

This is quite old question but I thought I would share my way :)

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
 window.scrollTo({
    top: $('#intro').offset().top,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  })
});
```

```css
.wrapper {

  height:1000px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #eee;
}

.other {
  height: 500px;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

#intro {
  height: 500px;
  background: #bbb;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="other">Other div</div>
  <div id="intro">
    Intro
  </div>
</div>
```